# How to test simple rake application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

i am using [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) for creating rest api i created the api and its working fine now i have to test this api.when we create rails api there is automatically spec_helper.rb file is generated now as usual first line for testing is

require spec_helper

please tell what should be the code for spec_helper.rb file

and other things i should focus when testing a simple rake application.i am giving a small code snippet for example i have to test

```
require 'grape'
require 'sequel'
require 'json'
module Twitter
  class API < Grape::API

    version 'v1', :using => :header, :vendor => 'twitter'
    format :json

    helpers do
      def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.authorize!(env)
      end

      def authenticate!
        error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
      end
    end

    resource :users do



      desc "Return a status."
      params do
        requires :id, :type => Integer, :desc => "Status id."
        optional :include , :type => String , :desc =>"parameter to include in "

      end
      get ':id' do
"Hello World"
end
```

in this grape application when i call localhost:9292/users/1234
then response should be "Hello World" how to test this app what should be content of spec_helper.rb file for testing.i am using only grape not using rails

Comment: in a directory i created an api .api is working fine how to test it

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to test.

Presumably the route you want to test (localhost:9292/users/1234) is a UsersController. That being the case, you will want to do something like this (using rspec):

```
    describe UsersController do
      context "GET#show" do
        it "should return 'Hello World'" do
          get :show, id: 1234
          response.body.should include 'Hello World'
        end
      end
    end
```

Now as for the rake task test, I would create an integration test that executes the rake task from the command-line and compares expected results to the output of the rake task sort of like this:

```
    describe "My Rake Task" do
      it "should return hello world" do
        results = `bundle exec rake my:rake:task`  
        results.should include 'Hello World'
      end
    end
```

Hope these rough examples work for you! Good luck!

UPDATE:

You should always write unit test on classes as much as possible so your rake task tests are very simple or not even needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean Rack app. There's a pretty decent section on testing in the README for Grape. You should start there. 
https://github.com/intridea/grape#writing-tests